# Intellij - marking blocks of code

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, refactoring, comments

I want to refactor large amount of code into new classes.
I need a tool that will let me mark parts of old code as 'done', so that I see what is left to do.

I imagine it as some colors in the background or in the margin. It would be best if I could use different colors or add comments to blocks of code. All of this should be local (I don't want git to show me differences with remote repository - and I don't want to share these notes with the team).

Do you know of any IntelliJ feature / plugin that allows me to do it?
I tried searching but it seems that I'm not using the right search words - I cannot find anything.

Comment: Would you consider tabbing in the sections that are done? You can highlight blocks of code and use tab to indent it. When you are finished, you can use format code function to set the tabbing back for the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

If you need just local solution, you can use bookmarks. Just create a TODO bookmark for each class or method and when you refactor it you can delete it. Then in the bookmarks list you can see all the sections that still need to be refactored.

See bookmarks docs for more info:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-bookmarks.html

---

Alternatively, you can use editor folding to collapse already refactored parts:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/